# How do I expose a User in Cloud Endpoints without passing around the reference?

Tags: java, security, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

In *Google Cloud Endpoint* I can inject a custom `Authenticator` and a `User` as shown below. I would like to expose the instance of `User` to service methods in a way similar to *Apache Shiro*'s `SecurityUtils.getSubject()`.

I have tried to do this by executing `UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser()`, but to no avail (returns `null`).

I've implemented some annotations that perform the authentication logic on services and I'd like to keep this separate from the actual business logic inside the services. Therefore it would be helpful if I could retrieve the current user belonging to the request that is currently being processed from anywhere. I'm implementing this without *Spring Security* or *Apache Shiro*.

Is there a clean way to do this?

```
@ApiMethod(authenticators = {JwtAuthenticator.class}, name = "find", path="foobars", httpMethod = GET)
public Foobar getFoobar(User user, long id) {
    // I'd like to get rid of passing the user reference
    return foobars.get(id, user);  // performs checks on user
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the way Endpoints is currently implemented, this is not possible to do cleanly using Framework idioms. If you stop including `User` parameters in your API methods, then authenticators will not be run in the first place, making it useless to implement an authenticator.

If you write your own auth code independently of the Endpoints Framework, then you can have static helpers that use `ThreadLocal` variables to store current users, which are filled through a servlet filter or some other mechanism.

Comment: This is what I ended up implementing yesterday. It works, but the logic is rather obfuscated and I'm doubtful it will withstand the test of time. I've therefore decided to stick with passing around the User. Thank you for your answer!